# How can i send new data to client API

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, post

I have been asked in interview "How will you send the new data to the client API"

what does it actually mean and how can i answer it.?

After research i found this i dont know weather is it relates to that or not.?

**Example #1 Using stream_context_create()**

```
<?php
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

/* Sends an http request to www.example.com
   with additional headers shown above */
$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: If you can not understand and explain the question from the interview, I dont think we will be able to imagine any thing. Having said that, my imagination of the question is that how do you update new data to the client without refreshing the page.

Comment: The question wants you to send data that has been created to an API (essentially another 'page'). Do you know how to send data from one page to another? It's pretty much just that. If the data is created without a form submission of any sort, you will need `AJAX`. If the data is able to be processed via PHP, you can use `$_POST`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge i know ajax and get and post methods but im not getting what she is expecting me to tell. she said client already has a api with some data and we want to add some more data to that API

Comment: Yeah shes asking how would you add data to that API if you know the AJAX then you do have an answer just need to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its depend on the flow process of that application itself,
There are many ways to send new data to client. Thats too general.
Either you develop it using websocket, or you can make background service that listen every request so you can trigger sending new data to client that listen to your application